# Installing php redis with igbinary, header file is not found

Tags: php, centos, pecl, phpredis, igbinary

I'm trying to install the phpredis extension, but no luck.

After running the command `./configure --enable-redis-igbinary`, I've received the following error:

> checking for igbinary includes... configure: error: Cannot find igbinary.h

igbinary was installed using PECL, but looks like the header files are not being found.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem is probably caused because PECL is installing the header files to a location different from the one that is used during the installation of phpredis. You can confirm this by looking at the console messages.

```
$> sudo pecl install igbinary
```

> Build process completed successfully Installing
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/igbinary.so'
>   Installing '**/usr/include/php/ext/igbinary**/igbinary.h'

```
$> ./configure --enable-redis-igbinary
```

> checking for PHP installed headers prefix... **/usr/local/include/php**
>   checking if debug is enabled... no checking if zts is enabled... no
>   checking for re2c... re2c checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
>   checking for gawk... gawk checking whether to enable redis support...
>   yes, shared checking whether to enable sessions... yes checking
>   whether to enable igbinary serializer support... yes checking for
>   igbinary includes... configure: error: Cannot find igbinary.h

Just move the igbinary folder to the correct location:

```
$> cp /usr/include/php/ext/igbinary /usr/local/include/php/ext/igbinary -fr
```

And it should correctly find the igbinary header file:

```
checking whether to enable igbinary serializer support... yes
checking for igbinary includes... /usr/local/include/php
```